# Is it possible to draw a 3D Choropleth Map in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, 3d, choropleth, maptitude

What I have in mind is something like these two examples below:

[image: 3D map 1]

[image: 3D map 1]

Also, if it is not possible to create a 3D choropleth map in ArcGIS, is there some other GIS software package that can draw 3D choropleth maps other than Maptitude?

Comment: re. the second part of your question: What is wrong with Maptitude?

Comment: winwaed, thanks for your comment. There is nothing wrong with Maptitude. In fact, I think it is a good GIS software package. What I really meant is that I am already aware that Maptitude has this option and I was wondering what other programs can also create 3D choropleth maps.

Comment: Possible in ArcMap Pro. (from lecture at OZRI2015)
Not sure about ArcMap under 10.3

Answer (score 6):

ArcScene is the ESRI approach to doing this. It is likely installed with ArcGIS so you should find it in the start menu.

This is a typical ArcScene map. Basically your attribute value can become the extrusion, you often need to normalize data.

[image]

Comment: To compliment this answer you would need to have purchased, installed and licensed the 3D Analyst extension to be able to use ArcScene. If you are using an Academic version you most likely have it installed and licensed. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Good point on the license.