# Making 3D choropleth map in QGIS 3 with native tools?

Tags: qgis-3, 3d, choropleth

This is similar to this question [Is it possible to draw a 3D Choropleth Map in ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122293/is-it-possible-to-draw-a-3d-choropleth-map-in-arcgis), but I just wanted to know if the same could be done with the new release of QGIS 3 without the use of the [QGIS2threejs plugin](https://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.io/en/docs/#).

I am hoping this is possible so I can have a little bit more flexibility by using the composer capabilities.

Comment: What if you try with 1) `Properties -> Symbology -> Graduated` 2) `Properties -> 3D View`, where Height is defined with the `linear_scale()` formula 3) And then `View -> New 3D Map View`?

Comment: Thanks - I cannot get it to maintain the colour ramp doing it that way. How do you define the height in the way you are suggesting?

Comment: somethig like `linear_scale("value", minimum("value"), maximum("value"),1,10)`

Comment: The formula is "scale_linear", rather than "linear_scale" - tested in QGIS 3.4